# convert a list of booleans to string

Tags: python

How do I convert this:

```
[True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
```

Into this:

```
'AB DE G'
```

Note: C and F are missing in the output because the corresponding items in the input list are False.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your list of booleans is not too long:

```
bools = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True]

print ''.join(chr(ord('A') + i) if b else ' ' for i, b in enumerate(bools))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [string.uppercase](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) instead of chr/ord. This will give you locale-dependent results. For ascii you can use string.ascii_uppercase.

```
>>> import string
>>> bools = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
>>> ''.join(string.uppercase[i] if b else ' ' for i, b in enumerate(bools))

'AB DE G'
```

Comment: @miles: you don't need list comprehension there

Comment: @SilentGhost: You're right, it's redundant. I've removed it now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: ''.join(map(lambda b, c: c if b else ' ',
                    [True, True, False, True, True, False, True],
                    'ABCDEFG'))
Out[1]: 'AB DE G'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
inputs = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
outputs = []
for i,b in enumerate(inputs):
  if b:
    outputs.append(chr(65+i)) # 65 = ord('A')
  else:
    outputs.append(' ')
outputstring = ''.join(outputs)
```

or the list comprehension version

```
inputs = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
outputstring = ''.join(chr(65+i) if b else ' ' for i,b in enumerate(inputs))
```

Comment: I would prefer enumerate(...) rather than range(len(...)).

Comment: Also, 97 -> 65 for uppercase letters :)

Comment: You're right, it's late and it slipped my mind. I've revised mine, but I also upvoted yours. :)

Comment: Thanks. It's early for me, so maybe I have an unfair advantage!

Answer (score 0):

Here's generalized solution based on [`numpy.where()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string, itertools

def where(selectors, x, y):
    return (xx if s else yy for xx, yy, s in itertools.izip(x, y, selectors))

condition = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
print ''.join(where(condition, string.uppercase, itertools.cycle(' ')))
# -> AB DE G

import numpy as np
print ''.join(np.where(condition, list(string.uppercase)[:len(condition)], ' '))
# -> AB DE G
```